# Asterisk: a little confused about the "parameters" of extensions

Tags: asterisk

Reading on [this wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Contexts%2C+Extensions%2C+and+Priorities) i see this extension

```
exten => 6001,1,Dial(PJSIP/demo-alice,20)
```

As I understand

```
exten is the extension
6001  the number to call
1     is the priority
Dial  the application to use
PJSIP/demo-alice is defined in sip.conf
20    ???
```

I don't understand the 20, is a timeout? Or what?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to incorrect way.

First read some book for beginner, like "Asterisk the future of telephony".

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Contexts%2C+Extensions%2C+and+Priorities

In your case Dial is "Application". Each application have its own params, you can find it in help on asterisk.org site or by doing

```
asterisk -rx "core show application Dial"
```

List of all applications is

```
asterisk -rx "core show applications"
```